# Cannot get useParams hook to work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a ticket management system. I am trying to get the ticket _id using the useParams hook from react-router-down. It returns undefined no matter what I try, and the error is "cannot read length of undefined"

I am at a lost. I am using it exactly how the documentations says use it.

I see the _id in the URL when i go to the protected route, So I know it's there.... i simply cant pull it when using useParams. I have tried everything.

here is my component with the useParams hook

```
import {
  Breadcrumbs,
  makeStyles,
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Paper,
  FormGroup,
  FormLabel,
  FormControl,
  Button,
  TextField,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Header } from "../Components/Layout/Header"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
// import { MessageHistory } from '../Components/MessageHistory/MessageHistory';
import { fetchSingleTicket } from '../Components/TicketTable/TicketActions';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";


const ticketPageStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  breadcrumb: {
    left: "25%",
    position: "relative",
    width: "200px",
  },
  link: {
    color: "#585858",
    cursor: "pointer",
  },

  div: {
    position: "relative",
    height: "1300px",
    top: "200px",
  },
  current: {
    color: "black",
  },
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
    margin: "0",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    height: "1000px",
    width: "1000px",
    outline: "none",
    overflow: "scroll"
  },
  text: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginTop: "30px"
    
  },

  

  button: {
      marginTop: "20px"
  },

  form: {
      position: "absolute",
      marginTop: "40px",
      left: "50%",
      transform: "translateX(-50%)"
  },

  input: {
    "& .Mui-focused": {
        color: "#585858",
      },
  }
}));

export const TicketPage = () => {
  const classes = ticketPageStyles();
  const   { ID }   = useParams()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

 
  
  console.log(ID)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchSingleTicket(ID))

  }, [ ID, dispatch])


  const onSubmit = () => {

    console.log("success")

  }


  return (
    <div className={classes.div}>
      <Header />
      <Breadcrumbs className={classes.breadcrumb} aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <Link  to="/dashboard" className={classes.link}>Home</Link>
        <Typography className={classes.current}>Ticket</Typography>
      </Breadcrumbs>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="flex-start">
          <div className={classes.text}>Subject: </div>
          <div className={classes.text}>Ticket Open: </div>
          <div className={classes.text}>Status: </div>
        </Grid>
        {/* <MessageHistory>

        </MessageHistory> */}


        <form className = {classes.form}>
          <FormControl>
            <FormGroup>
              <FormLabel component="legend">Please reply with a message here or update the ticket</FormLabel>
              <TextField
                InputProps={{
                  disableUnderline: true,
                }}
                variant="filled"
                id = "reply"
                name = "reply"
                label = "Reply..."
                rows = {10}
                multiline
                className = {classes.input}

              ></TextField>
              <Button onClick = {onSubmit} className = {classes.button}>Reply</Button>
            </FormGroup>
          </FormControl>
        </form>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
};
```

here is my app.js where the params should be coming from

```
import "./App.css";
import LandingPage from "./Pages/LandingPage";
import { AddTicket } from "./Pages/AddTicket/AddTicket";
import { TicketList } from "./Pages/TicketList";
import { Dashboard } from "./Pages/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import { TicketPage } from "./Pages/TicketPage";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { PrivateRoute } from './Components/PrivateRoutes/PrivateRoute';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <LandingPage />
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard />
          </PrivateRoute>
          <PrivateRoute path = "/add-ticket">
          <AddTicket />
          </PrivateRoute>
          <PrivateRoute path = "/ticket-list">
          <TicketList />
          </PrivateRoute>
          <PrivateRoute path = "/ticket/:ID">
          <TicketPage />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in the browser I see this when I click on a ticket

**http://localhost:3000/ticket/601c6e4863756fcd92477e24**

when I log the param it says undefined, and it my redux state it says it can't read property of undefined. I have A LOT more code I could show but this seems like the relevant code needed for this question. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I am stuck.

Answer found!!

The issue was with my private route.

here is the code for that

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { loginSuccess } from "../Login/LoginSlice";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchNewAccessToken } from "../../api/userAPI";
import { getUserProfile } from '../../Pages/Dashboard/UserActions';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isAuth } = useSelector((state) => state.login);
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateAccessJWT = async () => {
      const result = await fetchNewAccessToken();
      result && dispatch(loginSuccess());
    };
    !user._id && dispatch(getUserProfile())
    !sessionStorage.getItem("accessJWT") && localStorage.getItem("crmSite") && 
    updateAccessJWT();

   !isAuth && sessionStorage.getItem("accessJWT") && dispatch(loginSuccess());
  }, [dispatch, isAuth, user._id]);

  return ( <Route {...rest} render={() => (isAuth ? children : <Redirect to="/" />)} />);
  };
```

the line missing was this were these

```
 const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

!user._id && dispatch(getUserProfile())
```

I simply was not checking if the user was logged in on each route, but I was looking for the JWT only.

Comment: If you log the whole object from `useParams` before destructuring {ID}, what do you see?

Comment: Does it work if you replace `PrivateRoute` with `Route`?  Your code looks right to me so maybe there is something weird in your `PrivateRoute` component?  Otherwise I really don't know.

Comment: You are on to something with the PrivateRoute Component. I simply did not think of that! When I use Route it works perfectly. I was going down the wrong rabbit hole to begin with! Thanks!

Comment: Glad we got it narrowed down!  You should update your post with the code of your `PrivateRoute`.  I still don't know *why* it would be a problem.

Comment: I updated my question! thank you so much! Once I went there I realized exactly what I did.